# O que é o "Error cause" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

É comum termos erros lançados e estes erros terem que ser capturados e tratados de formas diferentes, de acordo com o contexto. Eu vejo (e uso) a prática de criação de classes personalizadas de erros (que ainda vou fazer uma pergunta específica sobre o assunto), como por exemplo (autoexplicativo):

```
export class InternalServerException extends Error{
  ...
}

export class APIResponseException extends Error{
  ...
}

export class DataBaseConnectionException extends Error{
  ...
}
```

O tratamento de erros feito sempre dentro do bloco `catch`, mas com o uso de `if`s para executar determinada operação de acordo com a instância do erro:

```
try {
  ...
  executaAlgumaCoisa()
  ...
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof APIResponseException) {
    // trata para o erro de API
  }

  if (error instanceof InternalServerException) {
    // trata para o erro interno
  }
}
```

O chato disso tudo é ficar fazendo `if`s e ainda ter que importar essas classes apenas para checagem de instância e saber de onde vem o erro, se é da API ou erro interno de aplicação, onde essas classes são as **causas**(*cause*) dos erros, para poder executar acões de acordo.

Um exemplo qualquer, executável para demonstrar:

```js
class NumeroParError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message)
    this.name = 'Error de Par'
  }
}

class NumeroImparError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message)
    this.name = 'Error de Ímpar'
  }
}

try {
  const numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  if (numero % 2) {
    throw new NumeroImparError(numero)
  } else {
    throw new NumeroParError(numero)
  }
} catch (err) {
  if (err instanceof NumeroParError) {
    console.log(`${err.name}. Motivo: ${err.message}`)
  } 
  if (err instanceof NumeroImparError) {
    console.log(`${err.name}. Motivo: ${err.message}`)
  } 
}
```

O novo recurso do JavaScript chamado `Error causes` veio para dar maior semântica aos objetos de erros e minimizar a quantidade de código a ser escrito.

- Como funciona esse recurso?
- Ele vai ser útil ao ponto de não ter que criar classes customizadas de error como `InternalServerException` e `APIResponseException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proposta [Error Cause](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-error-cause) é basicamente uma extensão aos construtores de erro nativos da linguagem para permitir a adição de informação contextual ao erro a ser instanciado. Essa informação é uma mera referência ao erro que causou um outro erro.

As causas de erro não são nenhuma modificação muito profunda na linguagem. São meramente extensões aos erros que, por adicionarem mais informações sobre a **causa** de um erro, ajudam em seu diagnóstico.

Sem a causa de erros propriamente anexada a qualquer um desses erros, não há, de fato, uma informação na *instância* do erro que informe exatamente qual foi sua causa. Claro que dá para diagnosticar pela *stack trace*, mas a informação não estaria nos objetos da aplicação, mas sim numa string que não é bem conveniente de manipular.

Para resolver isso, algumas pessoas poderiam optar por alternativas como:

- Criar uma subclasse de `Error` que permite a adição de uma propriedade que indique de onde o erro em questão veio;
- Estender a mensagem de erro, adicionando informação, não só do erro imediato, mas também sobre o erro que causou o erro imediato. Isso não escala muito bem.
- Bibliotecas de gerenciamento de erros.

Todavia perceba que nada disso é padronizado. Cada programador poderia optar por uma alternativa diferente sobre como lidar com a necessidade de adicionar informação contextual sobre a causa do erro.

Para resolver isso, decidiram padronizar isso ao nível da linguagem. Provavelmente foi inspirado em algo como o [`Error::source`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.source) do Rust e similares que devem existir em outros recursos.

Assim, um erro pode ser lançado já anexando o erro que o causou em sua própria construção. Roubando o exemplo da própria proposta:

```
async function doJob() {
  const rawResource = await fetch('//domain/resource-a')
    .catch(err => {
      throw new Error('Download raw resource failed', { cause: err });
    });
  const jobResult = doComputationalHeavyJob(rawResource);
  await fetch('//domain/upload', { method: 'POST', body: jobResult })
    .catch(err => {
      throw new Error('Upload job result failed', { cause: err });
    });
}

try {
  await doJob();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  console.log('Caused by', e.cause);
}
// Error: Upload job result failed
// Caused by TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Perceba que, ao adicionar informação sobre o que de fato causou o erro, a própria mensagem de erro pode ser amplamente simplificada. Compare com mensagens como:

- *Could not download resource because failed to fetch.*
- *Could not upload resource because failed to fetch.*

Nesse caso, alguns poderiam argumentar que o `cause` está fazendo pouca coisa – e eu concordaria. Todavia em situações onde os erros apresentam longas cadeias de interdependência em relação à causa, pode ser de grande ajuda ter como interligá-los pela fonte, ainda mais tendo em vista que a `cause` pode criar, de fato, um tipo de “lista ligada de erros”. Veja:

```js
const errorA = new Error('first raised error');
const errorB = new Error('second raised error', { cause: errorA });
const errorC = new Error('third raised error', { cause: errorB });
const errorD = new Error('fourth raised error', { cause: errorC });

try {
  throw errorD;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
  while (err = err.cause) {
    console.log(`  - Caused by: ${err.message}`);
  }
}
```

Testei no Firefox, que já suporta a nova adição (ainda não funciona no Chrome), e a saída ficou assim:

[image: Saída do código acima]

Veja que, como os erros estão ligados entre si (de modo muito similar a uma lista ligada), é bem simples obter informações sobre a causa na própria aplicação. Dá para usar a *stack trace* também, mas como ela não é bem padronizada, a tarefa pode ser bem complicada.

---

Em relação às subclasses de erro colocadas pelo AP na pergunta, a nova proposta não ajuda bem com isso.

Claro que, com a nova propriedade, a necessidade de se criar subclasses para *contextualizar* o erro pode diminuir, mas se você quiser tratar cada variação do erro individualmente dentro de um bloco `catch`, ainda terá que fazer aquelas várias verificações com o `if`. A nova proposta não visa ajudar com a discriminação de erros, mas sim os estender com informação causal.